# Why does my table hold duplicate primary keys?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

To my big (and worrying) surprise I just realized that my table with millions of rows, has a few handful of rows, where the primary key (ID) is a duplicate! I don't understand how this can ever happen, and how I might prevent it in the future?

The column holding the primary key is, and has always been, subject to a `CONSTRAINT fruits_pkey PRIMARY KEY(id);`

I'm running postgreql 9.3.4 on ubuntu.

**UPDATE**

**@Mat:** Datatype is `integer`

**@ypercube:** Yes, `select count(*) from (select count(*) from fruits group by id having count(*) > 1) as t1` returns `41`.

**@Craig:** Yes, I have done a failover before, and my slave is actually 9.3.3

Comment: So, does the query `SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tableName GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*)>1;` actually return rows?

Comment: Have you failed over to a streaming replica slave while running an earlier version of 9.3? (This symptom means index corruption; there was a known bug in 9.3 before 9.3.4 that could cause problems with replicas.) Also, go read http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption

Comment: What's ID's datatype and how did you find those duplicates?

Comment: @ypercube Even if it doesn't, they might still be there. You'd need to force a seqscan (`set enable_indexscan = off; set enable_indexonlyscan = false;`) to reliably see what's in the heap.

Comment: Without more details this question is not useful. Please add *how* you were testing and also test with the suggested method. Also add your table definition an other relevant details.

Comment: See UPDATE on question :-)

Comment: @CraigRinger, I think your suggestion is probably the case, what should I do in order to make sure my data is OK?

Comment: You need to upgrade your slave to 9.3.4 and then take a new base backup (i.e. re-initialize the slave) if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Also read the link by CraigRinger above.

Comment: Sure, now my master is running the data that has been "fallen over" a couple of times, and hence apparently holds a few rows with duplicate pkeys. I can just delete those rows on the master, and after cleaning it, reinitialize replication on the slave - right? HOWEVER - can I expect other issues apart from this with the duplicate entries?

Comment: @NielsKristian: you mean your master db version is 9.3.4, and slave version is 9.3.3?

Comment: Right, but the data on the master has been on a roundtrip through the slave, because I did a failover, and then restored the master from the slave later on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was all caused by the bug described and fixed in this release: http://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1506/

It caused us a lot of trouble!

Answer (score 1):

There is a free utility [here](https://free.justonedb.com/free-tools/) for fixing duplicate keys that violate PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraints in PostgreSQL as a result of bug #11141. It works by removing duplicates that are not accessible from the constraint index.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue right now. Duplicate rows despite a PK index. I could also not rebuild the index due to that.

I fixed it by making a group select with count(*) over the primary key columns with a where statement that forced a sequential table scan.

This gave me all duplicates and I could delete them to finally reindex the primary key. Hope this never happens ever again.

```
SELECT pk_field_1, pk_field_2, count(*)
FROM the_table
WHERE some_non_empty_other_column > ''
GROUP BY pk_field_1, pk_field_2
ORDER BY count DESC
```