# Duplicate rows with primary key constraint in PostgreSQL 10.6

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, postgresql-10, duplication, debugging

I have a table that's had `CONSTRAINT table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)` since setup.

However, I recently found that I have around 100 duplicate rows (I ran `select count(*) from (select count(*) from table group by id having count(*) > 1) as t1` as per [this old stack post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62675/why-does-my-table-hold-duplicate-primary-keys?newreg=50a2916e5dbd40028718ccdff160c83e). However, I'm running Postgres 10.6, which should be far after that bug.
Any ideas?

Comment: The postgresql mailing lists will be the best place to trouble shoot this. You have either found a bug or have hardware issues. Check your backup regime is working too.

Comment: Has this been pg_upgrade'd from a previous version, or was it on v10 since inception?  If the latter, what was the minor version at inception?

Comment: @jjanes this is a brand new table (so thankfully I don't have to worry about backups). I'm assuming 10.6, though I suppose it could have been 10.5

Answer (score 0):

I have some suggestions based on problems I had before, not with PostgreSQL 10, but with 9.1:

- Try to reindex
- Try `vacuum full analyze verbose`

If first two option don't work, try a dump and restore.

This happens because of a bug in indexes.

Comment: thanks, any advice for how to keep duplication from happening again? I suppose besides checking if a row exists before insertion...

Comment: Could you solve your problem ?

I suggest you maintain maintenance routine constantly, and always update your PostgreSQL version.